# What are "vectors on the unit-sphere"?

Tags: vector-analysis, normed-spaces, spherical-geometry, image-processing, dimensional-analysis

I currently read and try to understand [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6909819) and stumbled upon the following sentence:

> Given a distribution of **vectors $x$ on the $d$-dimensional unit sphere**, we consider a set...

and later:

> and as noted above, for a vector distribution on the unit sphere (as SIFT descriptors are)...

What do these statements mean? What are "vectors on the unit sphere", or more specifically "on the $d$-dimensional unit sphere"? Does this mean the vectors $x$ are $l_2$-normalized?

Comment: Vectors of norm 1 in $R^{d+1}$.

Comment: Vectors that points from the origin to somewhere on the unit sphere. Based on context, the norm is $\|\,\|_{\ell^2}$

Comment: Take a 2 dimensional scenario and consider an unit circle with center at origin. Now take 2-3 different vectors to see that each vector will originate from the center and will have only unit magnitude. Each such vector can be represented as $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle the vector makes with the X axis in counter clockwise direction. Now consider a 3 dimensional case. The unit circle will convert to the unit sphere, and each vector will instead be determined using the Direction cosines.Hope this helps...

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek that means the vectors $x$ would be $\ell_2$-normed?